# Unable to authenticate to Google Partner API

Tags: ruby, oauth, google-api, google-api-client

I am trying to invoke some methods on the Google Partner API via Ruby. Unfortunately I am unable to get past the following issue:

`Google::Apis::ClientError: forbidden: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

We have been able to connect to other apis (Drive/Sheets) using the same method.  I have added the Partners API to our developers console in the same was as Drive and Sheets.  There is no difference in the code below aside from the different API classes and the scope.

An excerpt of my code is below:

```
require 'google/apis/partners_v2'
include ::Google::Apis::PartnersV2
REFRESH_TOKEN = 'redacted'

client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file(Rails.root.to_s + '/config/google_client_secret.json')

@signet = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  client_id: client_id.id,
  client_secret: client_id.secret,
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/partners',
  refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN,
  token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  grant_type: 'refresh_token'
)
@signet.fetch_access_token!

api = Google::Apis::PartnersV2::PartnersService.new
api.authorization = @signet.access_token
api.list_companies
```

Update:

After authenticating the user with the relevant again now I receive:

`Google::Apis::ClientError: forbidden: The caller does not have permission`

Comment: I would try and authenticate your user again.  Sounds like its missing the scope in the refresh token you have saved.